# Pandas: Group by ID and drop rows containing the most NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a Pandas DataFrame where I have several rows that have the same ID. I want to group them by ID and check which row contains the least amount of NaN (or zero) values and drop the rest.

I want my final DataFrame to only contain one row per Id and the max amount of information WITHOUT iterating row per row.

In case two or more rows contain the least amount of NaN (or zero) values I would apply a second boolean filter which I have not defined yet. It would be something like this:

**Initial Table:**

```
     ID      A      B      C      D      E
1     4     56    NaN    890    aaa    907
2     4    NaN    NaN    890    aaa    907
3     7     89     78    754    bbb      1
4     7     89    NaN    754    bbb      1
5     7     89     78    754    bbb    NaN
```

**Final Table:**

```
     ID      A      B      C      D      E
1     4     56    NaN    890    aaa    907
3     7     89     78    754    bbb      1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one adding up the amount of `NaNs` per row and taking the `idxmin` within each group:

```
df.loc[df.isna().sum(1).groupby(df.ID).idxmin()]

   ID     A     B    C    D      E
1   4  56.0   NaN  890  aaa  907.0
3   7  89.0  78.0  754  bbb    1.0
```

Comment: Very nice solution, maybe also `loc` should be omit

Comment: not working without `loc`. He is using index of the rows with min 'NaN's